# Better stack trace

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, stack-trace

I am migrating an application from angular.js (version 1) to Vue.js version 2.4.

I am moving from serving original Javascript files in development mode to using Webpack, babel and .vue, which serves the processed Javascript files. Webpack and Vue.js are new to me.

When an exception occurs in the code, Vue.js or Webpack intercepts the error and prints a stack trace which is not helpful. Below is an example.

I am guessing that if Vue.js/Webpack did not intercept the exception, I could see the stack trace in the browser along with the code where the exception occurred.

Is there a guide to effectively using the browser debugger with Vue.js?

I am using Firefox and have the vuedevtools 2.5.9.

```
    [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: not a function"

found in

---> <QueryBuilder> at src/components/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.vue
       <Layout> at src/datamanager/Layout.vue
         <QueryBuilderPage> at src/datamanager/QueryBuilderPage.vue
           <App> at src/datamanager/App.vue
             <Root>  vue.esm.js:574

TypeError: not a function
Stack trace:
Promise@webpack-internal:///515:126:39
_rights@webpack-internal:///96:338:16
rights@webpack-internal:///96:461:16
created@webpack-internal:///304:241:9
callHook@webpack-internal:///2:2875:9
initMixin/Vue.prototype._init@webpack-internal:///2:4524:5
VueComponent@webpack-internal:///2:4694:7
createComponentInstanceForVnode@webpack-internal:///2:4208:10
init@webpack-internal:///2:4025:45
createComponent@webpack-internal:///2:5483:9
createElm@webpack-internal:///2:5431:9
createChildren@webpack-internal:///2:5554:9
createElm@webpack-internal:///2:5459:9
createChildren@webpack-internal:///2:5554:9
createElm@webpack-internal:///2:5459:9
createChildren@webpack-internal:///2:5554:9
createElm@webpack-internal:///2:5459:9
patch@webpack-internal:///2:5948:7
lifecycleMixin/Vue.prototype._update@webpack-internal:///2:2617:16
updateComponent@webpack-internal:///2:2745:7
get@webpack-internal:///2:3095:13
Watcher@webpack-internal:///2:3084:7
mountComponent@webpack-internal:///2:2752:3
Vue$3.prototype.$mount@webpack-internal:///2:8359:10
Vue$3.prototype.$mount@webpack-internal:///2:10699:10
init@webpack-internal:///2:4031:7
createComponent@webpack-internal:///2:5483:9
createElm@webpack-internal:///2:5431:9
patch@webpack-internal:///2:5948:7
lifecycleMixin/Vue.prototype._update@webpack-internal:///2:2617:16
updateComponent@webpack-internal:///2:2745:7
get@webpack-internal:///2:3095:13
Watcher@webpack-internal:///2:3084:7
mountComponent@webpack-internal:///2:2752:3
Vue$3.prototype.$mount@webpack-internal:///2:8359:10
Vue$3.prototype.$mount@webpack-internal:///2:10699:10
init@webpack-internal:///2:4031:7
createComponent@webpack-internal:///2:5483:9
createElm@webpack-internal:///2:5431:9
patch@webpack-internal:///2:5987:9
lifecycleMixin/Vue.prototype._update@webpack-internal:///2:2627:16
updateComponent@webpack-internal:///2:2745:7
get@webpack-internal:///2:3095:13
run@webpack-internal:///2:3172:17
flushSchedulerQueue@webpack-internal:///2:2934:5
nextTick/<@webpack-internal:///2:1796:9
flushCallbacks@webpack-internal:///2:1717:5
  vue.esm.js:1699
```

Comment: `Error in created hook: "TypeError: not a function"` does that not tell you enough already?

Comment: Honestly, it does not tell me enough. I cannot click on the message and go to the line the error occurred on.

Comment: Why would you even care about the line? The error message is sufficient from my perspective. Thankfully, Vue has very good error messages.

Comment: Is this sarcasm? That is the exception! As per my post, I want to use the debugger.When I get a browser stack trace, I expect to click on the line where the error occurred, view the code and add a break-point. Then, I re-execute the code and enter the debugger with the correct context. The dump above is not interactive, so I cannot get to the code. It does not list the original code line (but I have source maps enabled), so I cannot edit the original code to put in a debugger statement. It prevents the debugger from working.

Comment: For what it is worth, I get a much better stack-trace with chrome. Stack trace seems to use the source map and is interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be either that Firefox does not provide an interactive stack trace with Vue.js, or there is something wrong with my build.

I switched to Chrome and got a very usable tool. The stack trace shows the information from the original file. I can click to go the the file. I can set breakpoints, though the lines seem to be off (due to source maps I am sure).

Once I have a functional configuration, my pressing need for documentation is gone.